# Trying to write a batch file to open programs as an administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to write a batch file that will open computer management as an administrator (on a Windows 7 64 bit system).  I have done this successfully with cmd but cannot get it to work with computer management.
The command I have for cmd is:
runas /profile /env /user:username@domain cmd
After I authenticate with my pw, I'm good to go.

The commands I've tried for computer mgmt are:
runas /profile /env /user:username@domain compmgmt.msc
After I authenticate I get an error telling me "compmgmt.msc is not a valid Win32 application.

runas /profile /env /user:username@domain mmc
After I authenticate I get an error telling me "The requested operation requires elevation"

If I run the good cmd option then type in either mmc or compmgmt.msc, the program will open as admin because I'm in cmd as admin already.  I'm assuming there's a way to add onto the good cmd command to autopopulate that text into cmd and run it, but I don't know what it is.  I'm also open to trying other options, really I just want a tool that works.  I know that I can run my batch as admin and avoid all of this but the purpose of this tool is to not have to provide my admin username.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
runas /user:username@domain "cmd.exe /c \"start compmgmt.msc\""
```

If the `.msc` runs correctly from cmd, start cmd under the adecuated account and, from here, start the `.msc`

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks!!!  I was even able to modify the program to run most anything as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot run an .msc plugin without calling mmc. 
The correct call should be in this format:mmc.exe \location of plugin

```
runas /u:domain\user "mmc.exe \windows\system32\compmgmt.msc"
```

The start command will also work but relies on the extensions being properly entered in the registry. I usually do `mmc \plugin location` due to the different windows operating systems we use and the fact that usually half the plugins I want to use are not registered on the system for some reason.

Comment: In many windows the .msc are recognized and doesn't require to be launched from mmc.exe. On  windows10 you can use: compmgmt.msc   or mmc.exe "compmgmt.msc"

Answer (score 0):

better you travel to that location and then execute that file 
You can write batch file which will run:

(CompMgmtLauncher.exe or CompMgmt.msc)

It'll look like

C:\Users\Admin>cd\

C:>cd Windows

C:\Windows>cd System32

C:\Windows\System32>CompMgmtLauncher.exe

C:\Windows\System32>compmgmt.msc

C:\Windows\System32>